# found expression regular to keep url image without blank

Tags: regex

I'd like to get the urls from a string variable but only urls that do not have the file name as `blank`

For example, for this variable sting :

```
<img class = "lazythumb" src = "http://mytinywebsite.com/test/blank.gif" original = "http://mytinywebsite.com/test/test.jpg" alt = "">
```

I want to retrieve the url that does not contain blank. ie:

```
http://mytinywebsite.com/test/test.jpg.
```

I was  put this regular expression: `(^ https | http: \ / \ / * \ (:..? png | jpg))` that allows me to retrieve the two url starting with http or https is:

and I have this result :

> http://mytinywebsite.com/test/blank.gif" original = "http://mytinywebsite.com/test/test.jpg"

Now I'd like to have an expression that only returns urls that do not contain `blank`

In my example : I want to have result like

> http://mytinywebsite.com/test/test.jpg

Comment: is the blank always written before the file extension. i.e. before .gif or .jpeg etc

Comment: yes, is the blank always written before the file extension. i.e. before .gif or .jpeg etxc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the url not to have `blank` in it with a negative look-ahead:

```
(https?:\/\/(?![^"]*blank[^"]*)[^"]*(?:png|jpg))"
```

It's a bit cleaner if it's only the filename that can be 'blank' that you want to filter, with a negative look-behind:

```
(https?:\/\/[^"]*(?<!blank)(?:png|jpg))"
```

Comment: what if there is no double quote in the beginning like here : http://regex101.com/r/xL1jA0

Comment: Just remove the " from the beginning of the expressions (I'll update my answer as well)

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
[\w:\/.-]+(?<!blank)\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png)
```

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/aC4lB6